# Create BST from array of strings

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to create a functionality in C++ that can implement a BST from an array of strings, but it doesn't do anything at all and I don't understand what might be the problem. It should work recursively with for loop to iterate through all strings in an array.

```
void insertNode(node* root, std::string name)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        node* n = new node;
        n->name_ = name;
        root = n;
    }
    else if (root->name_.compare(name) <= 0)
    {
        insertNode(root->right_, name);
    }
    else
    {
        insertNode(root->left_, name);
    }
}

void CreateBST(node_t *& root, const std::vector<std::string> & array)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        insertNode(root, array[i]);
    }
}
```

I've tried to wirte recursive function to create a BST, while comparing strings from an array to set them as nodes.

Comment: For changes to `root` to have an effect outside `insertNode` it needs to be `node**`.

Comment: FYI, you can use comparison operators: <, >, ==, !=, <=, >=, with `std::string` instead of the `compare()` method.  IMHO, easier to read using the comparison operators.

Comment: also last compare is obsolete.

Comment: @Alessa when I've wrote `last compare is obsolete` I meant condition is obsolete since is covered by earlier `if` (you are in `else` section of it), code below is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this line

```
void insertNode(node* root, std::string name)
```

You need `root` there to be a `node*` reference (i.e. `node*&`) otherwise when you set `node` to a new value in the function that change is lost to the calling code.

Other possible issues include a typo where you use `node_t` in the other function, and you need to make sure that the `node` default constructor is nulling out the two pointers to children because your code assumes those pointers will be null after creation.